# cant start react native project using npm/expo start

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, npm-start

following [react-native docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) to make an android app after using

```
npm install -g expo-cli
```

command and in the same project file using

```
expo init first-proj

cd first-proj
```

everything is good until I do `npm start` it's going to give me an error

```
> first-proj@1.0.0 start
> expo start

Starting project at D:\react\react projects\reacttest\first-proj
Unable to find expo in this project - have you run yarn / npm install yet?
```

and so I downloaded npm by using `npm install` but now it's giving another problem.
when I type `npm start` it shows this in the terminal of vs code

```
> first-proj@1.0.0 start
> expo start

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './util/resolveCommand'
Require stack:
- D:\react\react projects\reacttest\first-proj\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\parse.js
- D:\react\react projects\reacttest\first-proj\node_modules\cross-spawn\index.js
- D:\react\react projects\reacttest\first-proj\node_modules\expo\bin\cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\react\react projects\reacttest\first-proj\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\parse.js:5:24)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'D:\\react\\react projects\\reacttest\\first-proj\\node_modules\\cross-spawn\\lib\\parse.js',
    'D:\\react\\react projects\\reacttest\\first-proj\\node_modules\\cross-spawn\\index.js',
    'D:\\react\\react projects\\reacttest\\first-proj\\node_modules\\expo\\bin\\cli.js'
  ]
}
```

And if I do `expo start` instead it gives

```
Starting project at D:\react\react projects\reacttest\first-proj
Developer tools running on http://localhost:19002
Cannot find module './lib/source-map-generator'
Require stack:
- D:\react\react projects\reacttest\first-proj\node_modules\source-map\source-map.js
- D:\react\react projects\reacttest\first-proj\node_modules\snapdragon\lib\utils.js
- D:\react\react projects\reacttest\first-proj\node_modules\snapdragon\lib\compiler.js
- D:\react\react projects\reacttest\first-proj\node_modules\snapdragon\index.js
- D:\react\react projects\reacttest\first-proj\node_modules\anymatch\node_modules\braces\lib\braces.js
- D:\react\react projects\reacttest\first-proj\node_modules\anymatch\node_modules\braces\index.js
- D:\react\react projects\reacttest\first-proj\node_modules\anymatch\node_modules\micromatch\index.js
- D:\react\react projects\reacttest\first-proj\node_modules\anymatch\index.js
- D:\react\react projects\reacttest\first-proj\node_modules\sane\src\common.js
- D:\react\react projects\reacttest\first-proj\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\lib\WatchmanWatcher.js
- D:\react\react projects\reacttest\first-proj\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js
- D:\react\react projects\reacttest\first-proj\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js
- D:\react\react projects\reacttest\first-proj\node_modules\metro\src\Bundler.js
- D:\react\react projects\reacttest\first-proj\node_modules\metro\src\IncrementalBundler.js
- D:\react\react projects\reacttest\first-proj\node_modules\metro\src\index.js
- C:\Users\abdal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\dev-server\build\metro\importMetroFromProject.js  
- C:\Users\abdal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\dev-server\build\HermesBundler.js
- C:\Users\abdal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\dev-server\build\MetroDevServer.js
- C:\Users\abdal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\xdl\build\start\startDevServerAsync.js
- C:\Users\abdal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\xdl\build\internal.js
- C:\Users\abdal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\xdl\build\index.js
- C:\Users\abdal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\build\exp.js
- C:\Users\abdal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\bin\expo.js
Error: Cannot find module './lib/source-map-generator'
Require stack:
- D:\react\react projects\reacttest\first-proj\node_modules\source-map\source-map.js
- D:\react\react projects\reacttest\first-proj\node_modules\snapdragon\lib\utils.js
- D:\react\react projects\reacttest\first-proj\node_modules\snapdragon\lib\compiler.js
- D:\react\react projects\reacttest\first-proj\node_modules\snapdragon\index.js
- D:\react\react projects\reacttest\first-proj\node_modules\anymatch\node_modules\braces\lib\braces.js
- D:\react\react projects\reacttest\first-proj\node_modules\anymatch\node_modules\braces\index.js
- D:\react\react projects\reacttest\first-proj\node_modules\anymatch\node_modules\micromatch\index.js
- D:\react\react projects\reacttest\first-proj\node_modules\anymatch\index.js
- D:\react\react projects\reacttest\first-proj\node_modules\sane\src\common.js
- D:\react\react projects\reacttest\first-proj\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\lib\WatchmanWatcher.js
- D:\react\react projects\reacttest\first-proj\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js
- D:\react\react projects\reacttest\first-proj\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js
- D:\react\react projects\reacttest\first-proj\node_modules\metro\src\Bundler.js
- D:\react\react projects\reacttest\first-proj\node_modules\metro\src\IncrementalBundler.js
- D:\react\react projects\reacttest\first-proj\node_modules\metro\src\index.js
- C:\Users\abdal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\dev-server\build\metro\importMetroFromProject.js  
- C:\Users\abdal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\dev-server\build\HermesBundler.js
- C:\Users\abdal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\dev-server\build\MetroDevServer.js
- C:\Users\abdal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\xdl\build\start\startDevServerAsync.js
- C:\Users\abdal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\xdl\build\internal.js
- C:\Users\abdal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\xdl\build\index.js
- C:\Users\abdal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\build\exp.js
- C:\Users\abdal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\bin\expo.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\react\react projects\reacttest\first-proj\node_modules\source-map\source-map.js:6:30)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
```

I need to use `npm start` so I can test the app on my real phone with the expo app. so what to do?

Answer (score -2):

Check to see if there is a `node_modules/` folder in your project.
The modules might not have been installed.

You need to run

```sh
cd first-proj
npm install
```

and then run

```
expo start
```

in the same folder (first-proj).

It should work after this.

Comment: you are not "installing" npm, you should already have it installed when you downloaded and installed node.js (did you do that), and then when you go into the project directory and run `npm install` you are installing the dependencies mentioned in your package.json file.